# make install not updating link

Tags: software-installation

I have installed emacs using

```
sudo make install
```

The above is supposed to make emacs available system wide

So how does the link in `/usr/local/bin` still point to the older version

```
ls -lrt /usr/local/bin/emacs

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 63 Jul 20 08:50 /usr/local/bin/emacs -> 
 /home/hagbard/Opstk/bld/emacs/emacs-29.0.50/src/emacs-29.0.50.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make install` cannot check and update all existing links.
The standard place for `emacs` is `/usr/bin`, so the link `/usr/bin/emacs` is now pointing to a new version. Other links were not touched.

Comment: When building from source, the default installation directory for the `emacs` binary is `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/bin`.

Comment: It is true,  `/usr/bin/emacs` points to `GNU Emacs 25.2.2` rather than the new.